# Mysql regex match names with a maximum of two words

Tags: mysql, regex

i've being trying this without success:

```
select * from table where name regexp '^[:alpha:]{2}$'
```

pls help me?

Comment: are looking for only two match result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There probably needs to be some white space in between the two words, right? Try

```
select * from table where name regexp '^[[:alpha:]]+[[:space:]]*[[:alpha:]]*$'
```

- `[[:alpha:]]+` matches one or more letter characters
- `[[:space:]]*` matches zero or more whitespace characters. (You may want to use `[[:blank:]]*` instead, to only match spaces and tabs, or `[[ ]]*` for spaces only.)
- `[[:alpha:]]*` matches zero or more letter characters

So this should accept strings like

- `"foo"`
- `"foo "`
- `"foo     "`
- `"foo bar"`
- `"foo    bar"`

and reject strings like

- `" foo"`
- `" foo "`
- `"foo bar baz"`

Comment: thanks, but in order to make this work I had to use, for exemple, [[:alpha:]] instead of just [:alpha:]

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from table where name regexp '^[:alpha:][:blank:]^[:alpha:]*$'
```

Comment: That can't possibly work, since each bracket expression will only match a single character, and the regex contains two _mandatory_ `^` anchors.